# how can i change the view when the url changed in ios webview app?

Tags: ios, url, webview

I created an ios Webview app and it loads a specific URL which is a login page. User fills the username and password and then click login.

I want my app to check the URL after clicking on login, that if URL changes to another URL (I mean if the entered user and pass is correct) the previous URL changes to a new one which I want and goes to next view with a new URL.

I would appreciate if you helped me with this instantly.

Comment: Can you edit your question with some of your work so far?

Comment: there is nothing special before that , except a loaded webview (a login page ) . do you need codes to understand better  ?

Comment: I mean work you have done so far to solve this particular problem

Comment: i have searched a lot about this and functions like webViewDidFinishLoad(_:) or shouldStartLoadWith but they don't do what i want  exactly